# C++: Efficiently adding integers to strings

Tags: c++, string, performance

I know how to add integers to strings, but I'm not sure I'm doing it in an efficient matters. I have a class where I often have to return a string plus an integer (a different integer each time), in Java I would do something like

```
public class MyClass {
  final static String S = "MYSTRING";
  private int id = 0;

  public String getString() {
    return S + (id++);
  }
}
```

But in C++ I have to do;

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  std::string S; // For some reason I can't do const std::string S = "MYSTRING";
  int id;

 public:
  MyClass() {
    S = "MYSTRING";
    id = 0;
  }

  std::string getString() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << S << id++;
    return oss.str();
  }
}
```

An additional constraint: I don't want (in fact, in can't) use Boost or any other librairies, I'll have to work with the standard library.

So the thing is; the code works, but in C++ I have to create a bunch of ostringstream objects, so it **seems** inefficient. To be fair, perhaps Java do the same and I just don't notice it, I say it's inefficient mostly because I know very little about strings.

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: You should read Herb Sutter's GOTW article, _The String Formatters of Manor Farm_ (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm)

Comment: Side-note: You can use `const std::string s` but have to initialize it via the initializer list: `MyClass() : s("foo") {}`.

Comment: I just got used to using string streams

Comment: @James & gf: Thanks for the comments. I'll take a look at the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::ostringstream` is the "standard" way to do this in C++.  You might be able to make something more efficient via some custom coding, or laboriously comparing the performance of `ostringstream`, `itoa`, and `sprintf` on all the systems where you'll be deploying this program, but it's probably not worth the effort.

I'd say the real problem with the `std::ostringstream` solution is not about efficiency.  The real problem is that the code just looks too complicated.

I know you don't want to use Boost, but if you look at Herb Sutter's [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm), you could just copy the (very tiny) definition of the `lexical_cast<>()` template into your program.  Then your code would look like this:

```
std::string getString() {
    return S + lexical_cast<std::string>(id++);
}
```

Whether this is more efficient than your existing solution depends on a lot of factors (how well your compiler inlines template instantiations, for example), but it definitely looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can do the following:

```
class MyClass 
{
 private:
  const std::string S; // For some reason I can't do const std::string S = "MYSTRING";
  int id;

 public:
  MyClass() :
     S( "MYSTRING" )
  {
    id = 0;
  }
}
```

Thats totally off the top of my head and untested though so I'm fully expecting tonnes of down votes :D hehehe

Comment: You *can* do this, but why do it? This will end up copying MYSTRING into every object of class MyClass, when you probably want a static const string that is the same single copy for every MyClass object.

Comment: @Zan: Functionally, this is identical to the C++ code Shinka provided, except that `S` is `const`.  He's answering the wrong question, but this is the right way to do what he expressed a desire to do.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers:

> ... the code works, but in C++ I have to create a bunch of ostringstream objects, so it **seems** inefficient. To be fair, perhaps Java do the same and I just don't notice it, ...

Java does in fact do exactly the same thing; + with Strings is syntactic sugar for `StringBuffer.append()`, so these do the same thing:

```
String f = "foo";
f += "bar" + "baz";

String f = "foo";
f = StringBuffer(f).append("bar").append("baz");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, ostringstream generally add overhead.

This is more efficient, and IMO is more idiomatic...

```
std::string adder() {
    static int i;
    char buf[32];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "MYSTRING%i", i++);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Note that, as written, this will not return the desired result if `i`'s string representation is more than seven characters long.  Maybe that's fine for your purposes, but it points to one of the reasons to prefer `stringstream` over the C-like techniques.